# What does “einen Teufel darum scheren” mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

Can someone explain me this phrase from *Die Unendliche Geschichte?*

> und die sich den Teufel darum scheren

specificaly I’m finding it difficult to find the translation of *darum scheren.*

Full phrase:

> Für mich sind Kinder nichts als blöde Schreihälse, Quälgeister, die alles kaputt machen, die die Bücher mit Marmelade vollschmieren und die Seiten zerreißen, und die sich den Teufel darum scheren, ob die Erwachsenen vielleicht auch ihre Sorgen und Kümmernisse haben.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=um+etw.+scheren Welome to the site!

Comment: http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~sich%20den%20Teufel%20um%20etwas%20scheren%20%2F%20kuemmern&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Comment: devil may care...

Comment: @ Robert think that comment gave the real explanation. Don't you want to put it in the form of answer,  so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 5):

You could say, "children [...] don't give a damn about the worries and problems of adults."

Comment: Technically, this answer is low quality. Unfortunately, it is also correct... so i have a hard time to vote to delete...

Comment: @Burki: Answers that are just low quality should not be deleted anyway. Deletion is reserved for answers that actually aren’t answers in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

> sich den Teufel um etwas scheren/kümmern

is an [idiom](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7Esich%20den%20Teufel%20um%20etwas%20scheren%20%2F%20kuemmern&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) that means to *ignore something* or to *not care about something*. However, for my feeling, it has often the much stronger meaning of: *someone doesn't give a shit*.

An example:

> Kinder scheren sich einen/den Teufel um die Sorgen der Erwachsenen
>
> = Children don't give a shit/ don't care about the troubles of adults (more freely: children have a devil-may-care attitude)

---

The original sentence is really long, so I shortened it to the important parts:

> Kinder sind Schreihälse, die sich den Teufel darum scheren, ob die Erwachsenen auch Sorgen haben
>
> = Children are squaller who don't give a shit/ don't care if adults have troubles, too.

Answer (score 2):

It generally means that you really don't care about something or are really inconsiderate (in a conscious way). So in this case it means that the children are inconsiderate about the worries and problems of adults :)

Comment: but that's not the "ob dieErwachsenen vielleicht auch ihre Sorgen und Kümmernisse haben" part ?

Comment: "und die sich den Teufel darum scheren" and "ob die Erwachsenen..." belong together. The first refers to the second.

Comment: ok, but what I'm not understanding is what exactly means the "und die sich den Teufel darum scheren" part. Because I can translate "ob die Erwachsenen vielleicht auch ihre Sorgen und Kümmernisse haben" by "that the aldults maybe also have problems and worries with them". But what I couldn't find was the other part meaning.

Comment: There is no real translation, as its just a saying. It roughly means, that you don't care about something or are consciously inconsiderate. You could maybe translate it with not giving a damn about something.